# Can't get my REST web service to work (using Glassfish in Netbeans)

Tags: web-services, rest, netbeans, glassfish, jersey

I'm writing a fairly simple restful web service project in Netbeans (used the Maven Web Application template). I am trying to run it on a Glassfish 4.1 server. I have used Tomcat in the past, but that's not really an option here. Basically, my problem is that I run the project, the server starts, but I just get a 404 error when I try to access the service in the browser.

Here is my source code:

```
package jp.go.aist.limrs;

import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Model;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.websocket.server.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;

@Path("/target")
public class ParserService 
{
    public static final String SERVER_LOC = "http://localhost:8080/LiMRS/";
    public static final String MAPPINGS_LOC = "export.txt";

    private String targetUrl;
    private String microData;

    private Model uDataModel;
    private Model mappingsModel;

    public ParserService() {}

    public ParserService( String url )
    {
        this.targetUrl = url;
        try {
            parseMicro(url);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/{url:.+}")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String getMicro(@PathParam("url") String target)
    {
        this.targetUrl = target;

        String domain = "_";
        try {
            URI uri = new URI(this.targetUrl);
            domain = uri.getHost();
            System.out.println("Domain is " + domain + "\n\n\n");
        } catch (URISyntaxException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(jp.go.aist.LiMRS.LiMRService.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        this.microData = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>" +
                "<rdf:RDF xml:base=\"http://dbpedia.org/ontology/\" " +
                "xmlns:_=\"" + domain + "\">\n\n";

        try 
        {
            parseMicro(URLEncoder.encode(this.targetUrl, "UTF-8"));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            return "";
        }

        return this.microData;
    }

    private void parseMicro(String target) throws MalformedURLException
    {
        try {
            URL url = new URL("http://getschema.org/microdataextractor?url=" + target + "&out=rdf");
            HttpURLConnection conn;
            try {
                conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");

                InputStream ins = conn.getInputStream();
                StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
                IOUtils.copy(ins, writer, null);
                this.microData += writer.toString() + ".";
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(jp.go.aist.LiMRS.LiMRService.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(jp.go.aist.LiMRS.LiMRService.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

The URL I'm using to test the service is: http://localhost:8080/LiMRS/target/http://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/jurassic_park/

(I know the URL is unencoded. There are forward slashes in the 'resource' part of the URL, after "/target/", but that is taken care of by the regex in the code and is not source of the problem.)

It's possible the problem is with the server itself, I don't know if there is any special configuration that needs to be done to Glassfish or if you can just run the project outright. I don't have a web.xml file. Unless I'm mistaken, I don't think I need one. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need a web.xml or a `Application/ResourceConfig` subclass to configure the application. If you don't want to use a web.xml, the easiest thing you can do is have an empty `Application` class annotated with `@ApplicationPath`. This will cause the registration of all `@Path` classes you have

```
@ApplicationPath("/")
public class JaxRsApplication extends Application {}
```

You can see more options [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30649206/2587435)

Comment: I still get the same 404 error. Just to clarify, is this a subclass within my REST service class? Or is it a separate class in the same package?

Comment: It really can go in any package (as a separate class file). I generally just put it in the root package of the project, but makes absolutely no difference. Put a print statement inside the constructor of this class to see if the logs. If it does, then the application is loaded correctly. You may be just accessing the wrong url. One thing that might be a problem (I don't know for sure) is the unclusion of another url in the main url. It might not be a problem. But check with a different simple resource method.

Comment: Is there anything else that is needed besides the annotation in the Application class and the annotations in my services class that glassfish needs to work properly? Does anything special need to be added to pom.xml, for instance?

Comment: No. If there is just an empty `Application` annotated with `@ApplicationPath`, it is enough. The value in the annotation will be used for the servlet url mapping. Like I said, check to see if the application is being loaded, by putting a log/print statement in the `Application` class's constructor. If it is, then the application is loaded correctly